# is there a way to perform multi-objective analysis with pygad module?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a system of equations using genetic algorithm (using python 3.x). is there a way to perform multi-objective analysis using the PyGAD module or an approach that increases accuracy of the GA output?

Answer (score 1):

From version 3.2 PyGAD is supporting multi-objective optimization. Citing documentation:

> To consider the problem as multi-objective, just return a list, tuple, or numpy.ndarray from the fitness function.

Example of code from [documentation](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pygad.html#preparing-the-fitness-func-parameter):

```
def fitness_func(ga_instance, solution, solution_idx):
    output1 = numpy.sum(solution*function_inputs1)
    output2 = numpy.sum(solution*function_inputs2)
    fitness1 = 1.0 / (numpy.abs(output1 - desired_output1) + 0.000001)
    fitness2 = 1.0 / (numpy.abs(output2 - desired_output2) + 0.000001)
    return [fitness1, fitness2]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 27 Jan 2024: PyGAD supports multi-objective optimization

PyGAD does not support multi-objective optimization at the current stage. Only single objective optimization is supported.